# Autosorting of Winforms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview

In Winforms, even if a `DataGridView` is sortable (the user can click a column header to have the rows sorted according to that column's values), when I programmatically add a row using

```
datagridview.Rows.Add(field1, field2, field3);
```

the new row is always put at the bottom rather than automatically being placed where it should be according to the current sort column and direction.

How can I put a new row in the `datagridview` so that it is where it should be according to the current sort settings?

Answer (score 1):

After you add the new row again to the data grid view, you can call the sort method to programmaticly sort the table:

```
DataGridViewColumn C = DataGridView1.Columns["Some Column"];
DataGridView1.Sort(C, ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: In that case, how can I determine which column the user has selected to sort the data by, and how can I tell which direction the sort is?

Comment: I want to keep the same sorting parameters that the user already had.

Comment: DataGridView1.Refresh() doesn't help?

Comment: @feralin: If I were you I would implement my own sort buttons so that I can easily keep track of both direction and sorting criteria